# Put iPhone mute On/Off programmatically. (Force Mute/UnMute)

Tags: ios, audio, mute

I am creating a tweak, and i want to "override" the Mute/UnMute programmatically.

I am fully aware that this is **Not** Apple approved.

How would i approach this ? Currently i can only set the volume down like so:

```
AVSystemController *AVSysController = [objc_getClass("AVSystemController") sharedAVSystemController]; 
[AVSysController setActiveCategoryVolumeTo:0.0];
```

Comment: Is this an Apple approved way of doing ?

Comment: No, Apple don't approve of "system override" code.

Answer (score 0):

I would just stick with changing the volume (heck, store what it used to be so that you can "u nmute" it later). Since there's a physical mute switch, it will be confusing for the user if the switch says the phone is muted when in reality you've unmuted it by yourself (or vice versa).

Comment: That is understandable but not an answer to my question. Also, it might seem confusing to the user in a normal situation, but the code is not intended for a normal situation.

Comment: What's the matter with mocking mute by storing, zeroing, and restoring the volume as I suggested? Will that be distinguishable from real muting by the user?

Comment: You cannot set the volume fully to zero, and the user's settings (Vibrate, blinking etc) will not be applied then. Again, not an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible. Since there is a physical switch available to mute/unmute the entire device, there is no software method available for it.

And even if someone tried to do it using private APIs , it gets conflict with physical switch available on the device.

May be just to give respect to available physical switch, apple has purposefully not provided software API for the same.

Comment: This is not possible with legal way. but muting the device is possible with private apis..no issues on it.. but if you muting the device programmatically, you have to handle the physical switch of a device. How physical switch will be handled programmatically?

Comment: Check again with the github link given by you. It clearly shows that they achieved the mute functionality by lowering the volume to zero. They haven't actually muted the system.                         Muting the system and lowering the volume to zero are two different technical concepts. First think what you actually need and you need that with legal or illegal way.

Comment: If you would like to discuss this further, this should be done in a chat, as stack overflow is Not a forum.